# Can't get Perl regex to be non-greedy

Tags: regex, perl, greedy, regex-greedy, non-greedy

My regex matches the last set of alpha characters in the line, regardless of what I do. I want it to match only the first occurrence.

I have tried using the non-greedy operator, but it stubbornly matches the right-most set of alpha characters, in this case giving $1 the value "Trig", which isn't what I want. I want $1 to be "02.04.07.06 Geerite".

#### Code

```
elsif ($line =~ /\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s[[:alpha:]]*?)/)
{
    print OUTPUT "NT5 " . $1 . " | | \n";
}
```

#### Source

> 02.04.07.06 Geerite Cu8S5 R 3m, R 3m, or R 32 Trig

#### Output

> NT2 32 Trig  | |

So in other words, I want this output:

> NT2 02.04.07.06 Geerite | |

Comment: Your output is prefixed with `NT2` not the `NT5` in your code sample, are you sure that this is the regex that is actually matching?

Answer (score 1):

If I change your code to

```
$line="     02.04.07.06 Geerite Cu8S5 R 3m, R 3m, or R 32 Trig ";
if ($line =~ /\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s[[:alpha:]]*?)/) { print "NT5 ".$1." | | \n"; }
```

I get this output:

```
NT5 02.04.07.06  | |
```

Making the * non-greedy, the word Geerite is included in the output.

Your observed output probably comes from a different branch of the if-elsif-else tree.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
perl -e '$_ = "02.04.07.06 Geerite Cu8S5 R 3m, R 3m, or R 32 Trig"; print "$1\n" if /(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d \w+)/'
```

prints:

```
02.04.07.06 Geerite
```

The regex on its own:

```
/(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d \w+)/
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers.  Indeed it was an error elsewhere in the elsif tree.

Answer (score 1):

Make `[[:alpha:]]` greedy:

```
$line = '   02.04.07.06 Geerite Cu8S5 R 3m, R 3m, or R 32 Trig';
if ($line =~ /\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s[[:alpha:]]*)/) {
    print OUTPUT "NT5 " . $1 . " | | \n";
}
```

#### Output

```
NT5 02.04.07.06 Geerite | |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can't match " 32 Trig". There must be some other problem.

If I add a space at the beginning of your example string and remove the ungreedy `?` after the last quantifier, it will produce the output you want.

```
$line =~ /\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s[[:alpha:]]*)/
```

The `[[:alpha:]]*?` will match as less as possible, so because there is no more pattern following, it will match  0 characters.